# Regex in R - Extracting two letters between spaces

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the two letters between two spaces -

```
AAPL US Equity
1836 JP Equity
APPLE SOMETHING NOT
C US Equity
```

Result -

```
US
JP

US
```

What I tried was `gsub("\\s[A-Z]{2}\\s", "\\1", vec)` but that gives me -

```
AAPLEquity
1836Equity
APPLE SOMETHING NOT
CEquity
```

which seems the exact opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
out <- rep("", length(vec))
i1 <- grepl("\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b", vec)

out[i1] <- sub(".*\\s+([A-Z]{2})\\s+.*", "\\1", vec[i1])
out
#[1] "US" "JP" ""   "US"
```

Or using `str_extract` to extract the two upper case characters after a space (specified by the regex lookaround) and follows a word boundary (`\\b`)

```
str_extract(vec, "(?<=\\s)([A-Z]{2})\\b")
#[1] "US" "JP" NA   "US"
```

NOTE: Not copied syntax from others' answer

#### data

```
vec <- c("AAPL US Equity", "1836 JP Equity", "APPLE SOMETHING NOT", "C US Equity")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gsub` command removes the parts of text matched with the regular expression. `\s[A-Z]{2}\s` finds streaks of whitespace, 2 uppercase ASCII letters and whitespace, and removes them from character vectors.

You may use

```
x <- c('AAPL US Equity','1836 JP Equity','APPLE SOMETHING NOT','C US Equity')
sub(".*\\s+([A-Z]{2})\\s.*|.*", "\\1", x)
# => [1] "US" "JP" ""   "US"
```

Here, the `.*\\s+([A-Z]{2})\\s.*` alternative matches those inputs that have a two-letter "word" between whitespaces and puts the words into Group 1 (`\1`), while `.*` alternative matches all other inputs to produce an empty result as the `sub` operation.

Or, you may  use

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\s)[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s)")
# => [1] "US" "JP" NA   "US"
```

Here, `(?<=\\s)[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s)` matches and `str_extract` extracts strings that are first two-letter words in between whitespaces.

If the words can be at the start/end of the string use

```
str_extract(x, "(?<!\\S)[A-Z]{2}(?!\\S)")
```